# Access geojson property of a layer in a featuregroup in Mapbox

Tags: geojson, mapbox

I have a GEOJSON which I added to the featuregroup in my Mapbox map like this:

```
var featureCollection = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "id": 1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [0, 0]
    }
  },{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "id": 2
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [30, 30]
    }
  },{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "id": 3
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-30, -30]
    }
  }]
};
var geojson = L.geoJson(featureCollection);
var featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
featureGroup.addLayer(geojson);
```

Now, I wish to access the id property of each layer while looping through the featuregroup, so that I can pass it as an argument to another function. In the case of a featurelayer, I can easily access it using something like this:

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(featureCollection).addTo(map);
featureLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  layer.on('click', function (e) {
    console.log('Clicked feature ID: ' + e.target.feature.properties.id);
  });
});
```

But I want to be able to access it while looping inside a featuregroup, and also I want to be able to do it without a 'click' or any such event. For example, something like this:

```
featureGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  var id = layer.feature.properties.id;
  testfunction(id);
});
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to do that. I've tried searching online, but because I'm new to this, I probably haven't been using the right keywords in my search.

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`L.featureGroup()` has a `toGeoJSON()` method you can call to get the GeoJSON for that `featureGroup`:

`var geojsonFromFeatureGroup = featureGroup.toGeoJSON();`

But this will just be the same thing that's in your `featureCollection` variable already. If you want to iterate over each feature in your GeoJSON, you can do so by iterating over the `featureCollection.features` array that you've already defined.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

To add to your answer, I recently learned about a couple of other ways to do the same thing based on my example.

I can loop through the "geojson" variable to access its id property:
`geojson.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  var id = layer.feature.properties.id;
  testfunction(id);
});`

Or, if like in this case, I have a bunch of L.geojson objects inside the featureGroup, I can use this:
`featureGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  layer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    var id = layer.feature.properties.id;
    testfunction(id);
  });
});`